# Can't get rsync to sync two external harddrives

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to copy files from one external HDD to another external HDD.
I use the following commands

`rsync -rv --exclude=.DS_Store ~/Volumes/Backed /Volumes/Hero`

where Backed is the source and Hero is the destination. However I keep getting this error:

> building file list ... rsync: link_stat
>   "/Users/Corbin/Volumes/Backed" failed: No such file or directory (2)

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and sync these two HDD. I'm using Mac 10.8 and both external HDD are formatted HFS+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks rather like one of your external HDs isn't mounted where you think it is.

'~' in that context refers to the user's home directory, so you are telling rsync that the 'Backed' HD is mounted in /Users/Corbin/Volumes/Backed. Is that true? I don't suspect that's a common place to mount things, so I'm thinking that what you want to do is drop that '~' and use just '/Volumes/Backed' instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was it. It's working right now. I'll check back when it's done.